# How should I connect the wiring for my ceiling light fixture?

Tags: light

I am trying to wire my ceiling light. When I connect white wire to white wire and black to black. The lights turns on but I cannot turn it off with switch see my wires from my ceiling and from my switch.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears likely that you have conduit, based on the colors here. You need to identify what wires are connected to the conduit that connects to the switch. And go back in time to slap whoever gave you two black wires to the switch, instead of one black and one other hot color, but oh, well. It seems quite possible that the junction box with the huge cluster of wires may not even connect to the switch, as that seems to be fed from the bottom and go off to the top, (or vice versa) with only black, white, and green in each conduit.

Comment: There are brown not black and were connected together with the black wire. I have them back the way it was

Comment: I was connecting the fixture wire to the black and white wire of the light. But the light stayed on.

Comment: That's more helpful! It looks like there were the remains of the original image, which wasn't that helpful, so I removed them. If you'd intended this to have 3 images, please edit again and include that 3rd one.